# MySQL AVG and Grouping

Tags: mysql, group-by, average

I'm struggling with a MySQL statement and was hoping for some guidance as I am close, but not quite there. I have a database that contains a table of property addresses and of property rental listings. The property addresses are related to a table or regions, which is related to a table of districts, which is then related to a table of suburbs.

I am trying to create a result which gives me the average rent in each suburb per month and by the number of bedrooms.

For example:

```
District Suburb     Month YEAR  YMD              Bedrooms DataAverage
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 1        190
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 2        274
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 3        341
```

Which I can then convert into a table as follows:

```
Average Rent

Beds by Suburb Jan-12   Feb-12  Mar-12  Apr-12  May-12  Jun-12  Jul-12
The Brook
    1          $150     $245    $160    $285    $135    $370    $350
    2          $330     $340    $380    $310    $335    $345    $355
    3          $350     $380    $310    $395    $380    $350    $350
Inner City
    1          $160     $245    $260    $285    $295    $300    $350
    2          $360     $440    $480    $410    $535    $545    $555
    3          $370     $480    $510    $595    $480    $450    $550
```

My Current SQL query is this:

```
SELECT d.name as District, s.name AS Suburb,
FROM_UNIXTIME(l.StartDate,'%m') AS Month,
FROM_UNIXTIME(l.StartDate,'%Y') AS YEAR,
FROM_UNIXTIME(l.StartDate, '%Y-%m-01 00:00') AS YMD,
p.Bedrooms,
REPLACE(FORMAT(AVG(l.RentPerWeek),0),',','') AS DataAverage
FROM properties p
LEFT JOIN listings l on l.property_id=p.id
LEFT JOIN regions r on p.region_id=r.id
LEFT JOIN districts d on d.region_id=r.id
LEFT JOIN suburbs s on s.district_id=d.id
WHERE FROM_UNIXTIME(l.StartDate) BETWEEN DATE(NOW()) - INTERVAL (DAY(NOW()) - 1) DAY - INTERVAL 11 MONTH AND NOW()
GROUP BY District, Suburb, Year, Month, Bedrooms 
ORDER BY District, Suburb ASC, YMD ASC, Bedrooms ASC
```

Unfortunately what I am getting is the same result for each and every suburb. I think I may need to create a subquery SQL statement to get this to work properly, but I'm not entirely sure.

So I am getting something like this:

```
District Suburb     Month YEAR  YMD              Bedrooms DataAverage
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 1        190
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 2        330
Nelson   The Brook  01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 3        350
Nelson   The Brook  02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 1        245
Nelson   The Brook  02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 2        340
Nelson   The Brook  02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 3        380
...
Nelson   Inner City 01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 1        190
Nelson   Inner City 01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 2        330
Nelson   Inner City 01    2012  2012-01-01 00:00 3        350
Nelson   Inner City 02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 1        245
Nelson   Inner City 02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 2        340
Nelson   Inner City 02    2012  2012-02-01 00:00 3        380
.etc.
```

```
Average Rent

Beds by Suburb Jan-12   Feb-12  Mar-12  Apr-12  May-12  Jun-12  Jul-12
The Brook
    1          $150     $245    $160    $285    $135    $370    $350
    2          $330     $340    $380    $310    $335    $345    $355
    3          $350     $380    $310    $395    $380    $350    $350
Inner City
    1          $150     $245    $160    $285    $135    $370    $350
    2          $330     $340    $380    $310    $335    $345    $355
    3          $350     $380    $310    $395    $380    $350    $350
```

Any pointers or assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that `id` is the primary key of each table, then according to your query text, a *property* is associated with a *region*, by virtue of the `region_id` column on the `properties` table:

```
      FROM properties p
      LEFT
      JOIN regions r 
        ON p.region_id=r.id
```

A *district* is associated with a *region* (presumably, a district is a subdivision of a region.)

```
      LEFT
      JOIN districts d
        ON d.region_id=r.id
```

and a *suburb* is associated with a *district* (presumably, a suburb is a subdivision of a district.)

```
      LEFT
      JOIN suburbs s
        ON s.district_id=d.id
```

The net result is that every property within a *region* is getting associated with EVERY *district* within that *region*, and associated with EVERY *suburb* within each *district*.

So, you are getting the rent values averaged for all properties within a region.

To get rent values per *suburb*, you really need the relationship between a *property* and its *suburb*.

What you really need is a `suburb_id` column on the `properties` table as a foreign key to the `suburbs` table.

```
      LEFT
      JOIN suburbs s 
        ON s.district_id=d.id
       AND s.id = p.suburb_id
```

Comment: Ah....egg on face... I already have a suburb_id column. I wonder why I didn't use that ???? Thanks for helping me to find the forrest amongst the trees...